# Java REST-ful server + Angular 5 client POST PUT syntax

Tags: java, angular, rest, crud

I am learning the HTTP REST/CRUD protocol on a test trying to get Java RESTful servlet and Angular5 client to communicate. I managed to make the GET and DELETE working, but despite of much searching unable to add or edit records in a db via POST, PUT calls.  I am guessing I am not passing the data right to the server by my client request. The error I get is:

```
[HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type]
```

---

Here is the applied code.
The servlet is a very simple Java app. auto-generated in Netbeans using:

```
"RESTful Web Services From Database"
```

implemented on GlassFish server. (This servlet can be reproduced in Netbeans with a few clicks without coding - see: [this](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/RESTfulWebServices/RESTfulWebservices.htm)).

Here is the relevant abstract of my servlet PlayerFacadeREST class:

```
@GET
@Path("{id}")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public List<Player> find(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
    List<Player> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(super.find(id));
    return list;
}

@GET
@Override
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public List<Player> findAll() {
    return super.findAll();
}

@POST
@Override
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public void create(Player entity) {
    super.create(entity);
}

@PUT
@Path("{id}")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public void edit(@PathParam("id") Integer id, Player entity){
    super.edit(entity);
}
```

The Player class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PLAYER")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Player.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Player p")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Player.findById", query = "SELECT p FROM Player p WHERE p.id = :id")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Player.findByFirstname", query = "SELECT p FROM Player p WHERE p.firstname = :firstname")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Player.findByLastname", query = "SELECT p FROM Player p WHERE p.lastname = :lastname")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Player.findByJerseynumber", query = "SELECT p FROM Player p WHERE p.jerseynumber = :jerseynumber")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Player.findByLastspokenwords", query = "SELECT p FROM Player p WHERE p.lastspokenwords = :lastspokenwords")})
public class Player implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;
    @Size(max = 64)
    @Column(name = "FIRSTNAME")
    private String firstname;
    @Size(max = 64)
    @Column(name = "LASTNAME")
    private String lastname;
    @Column(name = "JERSEYNUMBER")
    private Integer jerseynumber;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "LASTSPOKENWORDS")
    private String lastspokenwords;

    public Player() {
    }

    public Player(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    etc. - other: Getters/Setters of relevant fields
```

---

Here is my Angular client - relevant sections:

The class for the data object:

```
    export class PlayerRecord {
        id: number;
        firstname: string;
        lastname: string;
        jerseynumber: number;
        spokenwords: string;
    }
```

- the working part for GET:

  ```
  this.http.get<PlayerRecord[]>(url)
      .subscribe(data => this.onDataSuccess(data), 
                  err => console.log(err));
  ```

  and for DELETE - also works:

  ```
  this.http.delete(url + '/' + id)
      .subscribe(data => this.onDataSuccess(data), 
                  err => console.log(err));
  ```

**And here is the PUT attempt that does NOT work:**

```
     this.http.put(url + '/' + id, JSON.stringify(player))
        .subscribe(result => console.log('Http Success; ' + result), 
                      err => console.log(err));
```

Would you please explain what I am doing wrong and provide the correct syntax of how the 'player' needs to be presented to the server so it edits the record in the db?

Thank you.

Here is the logging output from browser:

Response headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Language:
Content-Length: 1207
Content-Type: text/html
Server: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  5.0x-powered-byServlet/3.1 JSP/2.3 (GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  5.0  Java/Oracle Corporation/1.8)
```

Request Headers:

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 70
Content-Type: text/plain
Host: localhost:8080
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Referer: http://localhost:4200/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0
```

---

On Pierre's advice I tried this:

```
     this.http.put(url + '/' + id, player)
        .subscribe(result => console.log('Http Success; ' + result), 
                      err => console.log(err));
```

but get error:

```
[HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error ]
```

These are the used headers:

```
    Host: localhost:8080
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0
    Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    Content-Type: application/json
    Referer: http://localhost:4200/
    Content-Length: 106
    Origin: http://localhost:4200
    Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: Why do you `JSON.stringify`? That's what's giving you `Content-Type: text/plain`, which your server doesn't consume.

Comment: I tried both, with and without JSON.stringify, both produce errors.

Comment: Different errors? Different content types? What if you test from a different client?

Comment: A 500 error is a problem in the backend, that's nothing to do with Angular. Please cut this down to a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the content type of your request.

> Content-Type: text/plain

I think to problem is right here :

```
this.http.put(url + '/' + id, JSON.stringify(player))
        .subscribe(result => console.log('Http Success; ' + result), 
                      err => console.log(err));
```

you don't have to transform your body as a string. So remove the JSON.stringify verify that the content-type of your request is application/json ( which your PUT route consumes ) and all should be fine

(if you use the new HttpClientModule the content type should be application/json )

Comment: Thank you. I tried that, but still no luck. I'll add the attempt to the post.

Comment: Thank you for help. I arrived to a working prototype - I will post as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I resolved this issue after days of research on HTTP, REST, CORS, etc.

It appears now there was an issue with some libraries/versions used in the steps above (generating the Java Web app and the "RESTful Web Services From Database" in Netbeans) in respect to the new GlassFish server.

I retried the same process from scratch, but this time starting with the Maven Web Application (not Java Web Application). It appears that Maven provided the correct/updated dependencies and all started working.

NOTE: Do not forget to include the step of: "Cross-Origin Resource Sharing Filter".

After the server app with REST service and CORS were generated via Maven, consequently ,in the Angular client web-app, the calls to the server with all the basic verbs: GET, PUT, POST and DELETE  started working fine:

GET (receive data):

```
 this.http.get<PlayerRecord[]>(url)
     .subscribe(data => this.onDataSuccess(data), 
                 err => console.log(err));  

 onDataSuccess(data: PlayerRecord[]) {
     // work with your data here
 }
```

PUT (edit):

```
 this.http.put(url + '/' + id, player)
    .subscribe(result => console.log('Http Success; ' + result), 
                  err => console.log(err));
```

POST (add):

```
 this.http.post(url, player)
     .subscribe(result => console.log('Http Success; ' + result), 
                  err => console.log(err));
```

I could have even disabled the CORS plugin in Firefox browser, that many have suggested to install. This is not necessary as our servlet end CORS Filter takes care of the cross-domain issue when developing in Angular and accessing our web server port 8080 from Angular on port 4200. 
Happy coding.